# Migrate docker microservices from OVH to AWS with Rancher?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, ovh, operations-orchestration

I've got a bunch of microservices (docker) which I  need to transfer/migrate from OVH to AWS.

They're orchestrated by Rancher.

What's the best/easiest way to accomplish that?

Also, I planned to use Kubernetes in the future. Should I somehow use it instead of Rancher here? Or should I migrate/transfer services with Rancher first & then make a switch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You’ll first need to draft your network setup as is on OVH, then design the same on AWS, first address custom overlay networks if any.  Answer questions like these in your design:

- Do you have overlay networks? If yes, which driver does it use?, can you redo the same on AWS?
- How’s the container inter-linking done is it shared file systems/volumes, or monitoring network/containers, or any association with physical host servers?
- If there is  shared storage on OVH that means you have data migration considerations to address before migrating.

This planning will make migration simpler. You can migrate to Rancher on AWS, then switch to k8s with ease.

Rancher makes it easy to configure, deploy and manage Kubernetes, on any infrastructure. This is an explanation:  https://rancher.com/kubernetes/.

And if your container runtime is purely docker, you can easily move the setup to AWS. Application setup is the main contributor to any complexities.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer microservices in Rancher is easy, you need add the new hosts (AWS) with other tag (aws=true), after clone all services with the new tag, copy filestore, network configuration and finally change DNS's entries.

I recommended migrate first to AWS and after to Kubernetes (you could use its with Rancher) because "decrease entropy" ;).

Comment: Currently Cattle is used as a default Environment. Do you suggest creating a new Cattle host on AWS first, clone all stacks with containers there, create a new Kubernetes host & then somehow migrate services from Cattle to Kubernetes? Isn't it the same as trying to migrate from current Cattle non aws host to a new Kubernetes aws host?